# Facing Pages in Pages 6.x

Tags: pages, internationalization, formatting

I think this question is fairly straight-forward: is there any way to get Pages 6.x (I have 6.2) to have facing pages? I typically word-process in Pages '09, however that doesn't have right-to-left support and I don't need Adobe InDesign for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, this question comes up frequently in the Apple forums, e.g.  [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/31958693#31958693).

Word Mac 2016 is supposed to be able to do mirrored margins and RTL.

Also I think Nisus Writer.

Comment: Apple really hasn't addressed that in the last four years?!

Comment: Progress in restoring lost Pages 09 features has been glacial.  We just got back linked text boxes finally.

Comment: Has anyone with contacts to Apple software execs tried to exert influence?

Comment: Also, Word sucks at RTL support. I'd use Pages '09, but that also sucks at RTL support.

Comment: @NoahM I would be interested in specific problems with word 2016 RTL if you have time .  You can email tom at bluesky dot org

Answer (score 2):

Facing pages are available in **Pages 7.0**.

[image]

> Turn on facing pages to format your document as two-page spreads.

This can be enabled as per the instructions in [Set up your document in Pages](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT206184#facing_mac)

> #### Use facing pages
>
> You can set your document up as a two-page spread. Documents set up as two-page spreads can have different headers, footers, and master objects on left- and right-facing pages. Use facing pages for layouts for printed books, or for double-sided documents that you intend to print.
>
> [image]
>
> 1. Click [image: Document], then click Document.
> 2. Select Facing Pages.
> 3. If you want different footers for the left and right facing pages:
>
>    - Click [image: Document], then click Section.
>    - Select "Left and right pages are different."
>
> You can view facing pages as a two-page spread, or as a single page. Click Zoom, then choose Two Pages or One Page. If you're viewing your document as a two-page spread, choose Fit Spread to fit the two-page spread vertically on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to resolve this issue by opening the Pages document in OOD and there it can be formatted with mirror margins. It worked.  Negatively this process changed some fonts (from italic to normal)  issues. So, if you are aware of the pitfalls you can produce a document for printing (OOD is free)
Now I am back to square 1, wondering what can be done as this is a large document and easy to miss bugs. Apache Open Office 4 was the program I used.  Marie

Comment: The question is about how to do it in Pages, not in Word, OpenOffice, LibreOffice, or Nisus Writer.  All you are doing is telling people to use a different app,